# how to get "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl" from json because @ is a keyword and canno be used for variables. @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl cant declare

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, microsoft-graph-api

import Foundation
import UIKit

struct OnedriveItemsData: Decodable {

```
let value : [Value]
```

}

struct Value: Decodable {

```
let name: String
let @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl:String
```

}

Here @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl cannot be declared and giving error beacuse it starts with @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First give a name of the property like `downloadUrl`. To match it with server response add the property to `CodingKeys` enum. For more information please check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

```
struct Value: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let downloadUrl: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case downloadUrl = "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"
    }
}
```

Comment: Done. Ty again.